# Tag page into the Feed Facebook with Android

Tags: android, facebook, post, tags, feed

I have an application that is going to post on the wall with the method FEEd but I would like to link a name to a specific page.

I found that if I put this code: @[116380291722462:1:TicinoCinema]  in this url:  http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed. It's work but If I do this by Facebook api it's dosen't work

Method:  String response = facebook.request("feed", params, "POST");

Param: params.putString("message", Utils.getTextCheckIn(location, "@[116380291722462:1:TicinoCinema]"));

What is the problem? When I am going to do this post I can't  see the name TICINOCINEMA but the rest I can see, the api just remove my "tag" and post the message.

There is any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the tagging in wall post is currently not supported via the feed dialog or other APIs. Please follow our [developers blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) to stay tuned on new API launches and updates.